# C++11 Передача функции-члена класса как компаратора

Tags: c++, ооп, c++11, stl

Есть класс `Tree` в нем есть `vector<Path*>` и его нужно отсортировать. Написал компаратор:

```
bool Tree::PathComparator(Path* a, Path* b)
{
    return a->GetPath() < b->GetPath();
}
```

Попытался отсортировать

```
sort(pathes.begin(), pathes.end(), PathComparator);
```

выдает ошибку:

*error C3867: Tree::PathComparator: в вызове функции отсутствует список аргументов; используйте "&Tree::PathComparator" для создания указателя на член*

*error C2780: void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt): требует аргументов: 2, имеется: 3*

Но если сделать компаратор обычной функцией, а не членом класса, то все работает. И мне стало интересно почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция_член `bool Tree::PathComparator(Path* a, Path* b)` (и любая другая функция_член класса) неявно получает  в свой первый аргумент объект `*this`, то есть, в данном случаи у вас будет в аргументах (Tree&, Path* a, Path* b). Это есть основное отличие функции_члена от свободной(обычной по вашему определению) функции.

В таких случаях проще определить оператор `<`для класса, и компаратор не нужно будет передавать: Но если нужно сравнивать указатели, это значит, что, скорее всего, вы что то делаете не так

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Я сравниваю не указатели, в данном случае `a->GetPath()` возвращает числовое значение, рассчитанное до этого

Comment: А еще этот компаратор можно сделать статическим членом класса.